# Why is CSV "better" than Excel in 5 star open data schema?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, 5-star-scheme

I am reading about the 5-star schema for **Open** data. I noticed that the data ranked with three stars are CSV files while data ranked as two stars are like Excel documents. I wonder why is that?

Is excel less quality than CSV?

Is it because for excel we need a specific application to open it while we can process CSV easily using any text editor?

#### Edit

I have been reading about it and I found the followings: **I am not sure if this is correct or not**:

1. The two-star-data is data that is formatted under a *Close Format* or *Proprietary Format*, which is a way of storing the data according to a specific encoding format that is either secret or not allowed to use in an open license.
2. The three-star-data is data that is formatted under an *Open format* or *Non-Proprietary Format*, which is a way of storing the data according to a specific encoding format that is allowed to use by anyone.

Is that correct, please?

Answer (score 6):

Quality of the file format doesn’t matter. And it doesn’t matter if a specific application is needed for working with the file format (or if there exists such an application at all).

It only matters if the file format is [proprietary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_format) or [open/free/libre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_format).

With "excel", Tim Berners-Lee probably refered to the **Excel Binary File Format**, which is one of several formats supported by the software Microsoft Excel (and [according to its Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats), it was the default format up until 2007; newer versions seem to use an open format by default, [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)). This format is proprietary.

The **CSV** format is open, standardized by [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

So:

- You can get 3 stars if you use a "non-proprietary" file format.
- You can’t get more than 2 stars if you use a proprietary file format.

Comment: CSV also is superior to Excel for being a simpler overall format that is only capable of holding the raw data. Excel files can hold all kinds of formatting, cell formulae, etc. CSVs hold the data. There's a lot less complexity to parsing that.

Comment: I don't think using reduced complexity of parsing from Excel to CSV is a valid argument, I mean when you get to 4 star and 5 star, we're talking using about RDF; RDF can be incredibly difficult to parse.